# Dropdown Menu to Query Database

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

First of I apologize if this is a dumb question - I'm just starting to pick up my php/mysql skills. I'm making a dropdown form with 3 dropdowns. I want to be able to trigger a query from the form. You select Part Type, Make, Model hit submit and a table of results is displayed.

I have my form populated with 3 arrays and when you hit submit, I can echo the key of each selected item to the page:

```
    echo '<form action="dbBrowse.php" method="post">';

    $mak = array (0 => 'Make', 'Ford', 'Freightliner', 'Peterbilt', 'Sterling', 'Mack', 'International', 'Kenworth', 'Volvo');
    $mod = array (0 => 'Model', 'Argosy', 'Midliner');
    $p = array (0 => 'Part', 'Radiator', 'Charge Air Cooler', 'AC');                        



    echo '<select name="drop1">';
    foreach ($p as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\">
    $value</option>\n";

    }


    echo '</select>';




    echo '<select name="drop2">';
    foreach ($mak as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\">
    $value</option>\n";



    }

    echo '<select/>';



    echo '<select name="drop3">';
    foreach ($mod as $key => $value)  {
    echo "<option value=\"$key\">
    $value</option>\n";



    }

    echo '<select/>';
    echo '</form>';


            //echo keys of selection
    echo $_POST['drop1'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $_POST['drop2'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $_POST['drop3'];
            //these echo something like 1, 1, 3 etc. to my page
```

Where I'm getting lost is I'm looking to take the selected options and insert them into a query something like this:

```
     $dropSearch = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part= "$partTypeVar" . AND  WHERE make = "$makeTypeVar" . AND WHERE model = "$modelTypeVar"');    

            $partTypeVar being the corresponding value to the key that is being returned from the array.
```

I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out how to make that happen. Eventually I want to expand this further but just being able to create a mysql statement with the values selected would make my day right now. I understand the concept of what needs to happen but I'm unsure of how to accomplish it. Any help or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to make a cascading drop-down list in PHP using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857287/cascading-drop-down-list)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137357

Comment: Where do you specify the variable's $drop1, $drop2, $drop3 ?

Comment: stUrb I apologize I just reedited it to remove the $.

Comment: they were just the name of dropboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to delete the . char in your SQL query, there's no need to use it for now and of course assign the correct values to the variables.

```
$partTypeVar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['$drop1']);
$makeTypeVar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['$drop2']);
$modelTypeVar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['$drop3']);

$dropSearch = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part= "$partTypeVar" AND WHERE make = "$makeTypeVar" AND WHERE model = "$modelTypeVar"');
```

I am assuming that's the correct order of your variables.

I hope this help!

Comment: thanks for the help. I made some adjustments and got a basic version of what Im trying to do. Man, what do you think the best way to learn php/mysql? Just getting in and doing small projects? Thats what Ive started doing but I always run into things I want to do and questions that arent in a book or discussed in tutorial. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just read tutorials and best practices. Ask, ask and ask once and once again. :P When you have problems with some functions, just go to http://php.net/ and read about it.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, when the `form` is submitted, you want to `query` the database with the selected values.

**Example using `AND`:**

```
// Prepare the Query
$query = sprintf(
           "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part='%s' AND make='%s' AND model='%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop1']),
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop2']),
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop3'])
         );

// Execute the Query
mysql_query($query);
```

*This will select all rows from the table parts that match those three values.*

**Example using `OR`:**

```
// Prepare the Query
$query = sprintf(
           "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part='%s' OR make='%s' OR model='%s'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop1']),
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop2']),
           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drop3'])
         );

// Execute the Query
mysql_query($query);
```

*This will select all rows from the table parts that match any of those three values.*

**You can read more about this:**

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

[MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) :: [12 Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions.html) :: [12.3 Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="myFilter">
<option value="Chooseafilter" name="default">Choose a filter...</option>
<option value ="Lastname" name="opLastName">Last Name</option>
<option value="Firstname" name="opFirstName">First Name</option>
<select>
<li><!--TEXT SEARCH INPUT--><input type="text" name="search_filter" /></li> 
...
dbconnection();#assume that all connection data is here        
...
$filter = $_POST['myFilter']; #
...

switch($filter)
    {
        case "Lastname":
        $selectedoption = "profile_name";
        break;

        case "Firstname":
        $selectedoption="profile_first_name";
        break;

        case "Chooseafilter":
        $selectedoption = "";
        break;  
    }           

$result = pg_query($db_con, "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE ".$selectedoption." LIKE'%$_POST[search_filter]%'"); 
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);  
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo"<ul>  
                <form name='update' action='' method='POST'>
                <li>Guest Last Name:</li>
                <li><input type='text' name='profile_name_result' value='$row[profile_name]' /></li>  
                <li>Guest First Name:</li>
                <li><input type='text' name='profile_first_name_result' value='$row[profile_first_name]' /></li>  
                <li><input type='submit' value='Update' name='update'></input></li>
    ...
```