# get selected item from a dropdown list and save it to a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list(in a php file and without form tag)

```
print "<select id="animal" onchange="getSelectedItem(this.value)">
<option value = "Dog"> Dog </option>
<option value = "Cat"> Cat </option>
</select>";
```

and a variable $selAnimal

and a javascript function

```
function getSelectedItem(opt){
    //$selAnimal = opt <- how do i do this?
}
```

As much as possible I wouldn't like the page to reload so I avoid putting this inside a form and submitting as I select. I can't get to make $.post method work. I know for a fact that this cannot be directly done since php is server side and javascript is client side. 
I also thought of putting the selected value inside a hidden component(span or something) and get the value from it. But I have no idea how to get it from the component. I've also seen use of AJAX or jquery but I'm not really knowledgeable enough.

I need to save this value to the php variable since I'll be using it as basis for the options in my second dropdown. For example, if I choose Dog, the dropdown list would have dog breeds as options.

I've spent days looking for possible solutions everywhere. Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes I've tried some, one which requires reload or submit but I as I said, I'd like to avoid it. I tried post as well. But I can't make it work. I've used $post before in exporting images from charts and it worked. But this time, I can't make it work.

Comment: something like $.post("file.php", name: opt); and
$selname = $_POST["name"]; but this doesn't work T_T

Comment: here are some links [Cascading dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857287/how-to-make-a-cascading-drop-down-list-in-php-using-jquery)

Comment: I tried jquery and it works perfecty fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animal').change(function(){
    $.post('loadbreeds.php', { animal:$('#animal').val() },
        function(data){
            $('#breedList').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post" >
    <div id="animalList">
        <select id="animal" name="animal">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php if (!empty($animals)) { foreach ($animals as $value) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['animalKey']; ?>"><?php echo $value['animalName']; ?></option>
            <?php }} ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="breedList">
        <select id="breed" name="breed">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

code for loadbreeds.php

```
$animalKey = $_POST['animal'];
$breeds = selectByKey($animalKey); // code for selecting breeds

<select id="breed" name="breed">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php if (!empty($breeds)) { foreach ($breeds as $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['breedKey']; ?>"><?php echo $value['breedName']; ?></option>
    <?php }} ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the variable available to the same file since PHP declares all its variables before the JS even starts. You can however simply redirect the user to a new file where the variable is available.

Use something like this:

```
function getSelectedItem(opt){
    location.href = location.href + "?selAnimal=" + opt;
}
```

In PHP, now you can use the selAnimal variable to display something different, like this:

```
$selectedAnimal = $_GET["selAnimal"];
if($selectedAnimal == "dog"){
    // Whatever you want to do now
}
```

A better way would be to use POST with forms, but this should work fine for you as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this one before. But I think this redirects the page into the same page but with the option appended on the url.

Comment: @user974227 Yes, that is what it does. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: it does but I don't need to reload the whole page

Comment: @user974227 You'll have to do that if you want to get your value to PHP. If possible, you could try using a JS solution to building the new options.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, to rebuild the second dropdown:

http://jsfiddle.net/kAY7M/59/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var AnimalTypeList = [\"Dog1,Dog2,Dog3,Dog4\",\"Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4\"];</script>";

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#animal").change(function () {
    var sel = $("#animal").prop("selectedIndex") - 1;
    var list = AnimalTypeList[sel].split(",");
    var Counter = list.length;
    $("#type").children().remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < Counter; i++) {
        $("#type").append("<option value = '" + list[i] + "'> " + list[i] + "</option>");
    }    
})

</script>
```

I could do a pure Javascript only version too, but that is a bit more code.